# Dijkstra Time Complexity Clarification

Tags: python, graph, shortest-path, dijkstra, path-finding

For Dijkstra implementation that uses a minimum heap priority queue, I set it up as to find a station that does not exist on the network, so that it has to check everything. My question is since the overall time complexity `O(V + E log V)`, why is the time taken for a network to find locate the minimum distance to a station that does not exist on a network with 500 Edges and 400 Stations longer than one with 500 Edges and 500 Stations?

Note: All stations are connected by at least 1 edge. Station with |E| = |S| + 100 has 100 extra edges that are unique but randomly connected

```
#  PSEUDOCODE

1. INIT QUEUE & DICTIONARY WITH DISTANCE TO SOURCE BEING INF
2. ENQUEUE SOURCE WITH DISTANCE 0
3. SET DISTANCE TO SOURCE FOR SOURCE TO 0
4. LOOP WHILE QUEUE NOT EMPTY
      a. POP STATION FROM QUEUE (CALL IT P)
      b. IF P MARKED AS VISITED THEN RESTART LOOP (CONTINUE).
      c. IF P == TARGET RETURN DIST
      d. LOOP THROUGH ALL ADJACENT STATIONS (A) TO P
          i. IF (A IS NOT MARKED AS VISITED) AND (DIST TO P + DIST(P,A) < DIST TO A)
             1. CHANGE DIST TO A TO BE THE NEW DIST
             2. PUSH A ONTO THE PRIORITY QUEUE.
```

[image: Graph and Table depicting experimental time complexity]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Arne is right, this question depends a lot on the actual graph used.

|E| = |S| makes for a very very sparse graph. Let's take an extreme example. Let's say you have |S| = 500, |E| = 500, and all nodes are neatly arranged in a circle. At each iteration, the algorithm goes:

- Take a single node from the priority queue.
- Follow the single edge.
- Add a single node to the PQ.

All the time, the PQ is running close to empty. The PQ is an optimization over a regular queue, but if there is only one node in the queue, then there is not much to optimize. There is no point of talking about O(log N) when you know N is always 1. Actual performance is much better than the worst-case performance predicted by Big-Oh notation.

Now add 100 edges. Suddenly the algorithm has choices! The PQ fills up. Let's say the first node examined has 10 edges, and consequently the PQ has a size of 10. It might stay this size for dozens of iterations. The PQ finally has some work to do! This is where the extra time consumption comes from.

P.S. it's Dijkstra, not Djikstra.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that when you say

> why is the time taken for a network to find locate the minimum distance to a station that does not exist on a network with 500 Edges and 400 Stations longer than one with 500 Edges and 500 Stations?

you don't mean that this were true for any pair of graphs with the stated numbers of nodes and edges (because it isn't), but just that it is true for one particular pair of graph instances that you constructed and tested.

The time complexity statement, on the other hand, gives a general upper bound for any graph instance with the given numbers of nodes and edges. In other words, it is a worst case scenario, designed to be true even for the one nasty graph that is hardest for the algorithm to handle quickly.

So there is no contradiction. You just happened to pick graph instances where the smaller graph actually makes it harder for the algorithm to discover that there is no path. Regardless of this example, for the worst possible graph with 400 nodes (and 500 edges), the algorithm would still be faster than for the worst possible graph with 500 nodes (and 500 edges).

Comment: yes I would agree, but this was based off experimental time, I added a graph with the results using the timeit library. Is there any reason that the algorithm would cause it?

Comment: Again, it depends on which specific graph instances you chose for the tests. I understand each node has at least one edge, but how did you pick the other nodes for those edges, and how did you set the edge lengths?

Comment: I didn't set an edge length, I'm searching for a station that does not exist on the network, s.t. that all the stations must be visited. The random +100 edges are unique but randomly connected (i.e. the two station connected are random, but do not have a pre existing edge). Position of the nodes on the network are randomly generated so the lengths of edges are random too. There seems to be some sort of correlation for the results, or am I wrong to assume so?